# How do I make my splash screen load faster like Snapchat and others

Tags: android

My splash screen on Android Studio loads a grey background before it goes to my splash screen and then the main activity.

How do I make the grey loader the splash screen?

Comment: Not certain, but perhaps it's the size of your image? If it's too big it will take a long time to load.

Comment: Provide some more context. What is your splash screen? How do you show it? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have done lots of programming in oncreate() method. keep it as minimal as possible. check this useful tutorial for splash screen: http://tusharpatil.com/blog/how-to-implement-splash-screen-in-android-java/

Answer (score 0):

Your splash activity is most likely quite heavy. You can add a very minimal activity that just forwards on to your larger splash activity

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Use that activity as the launching intent in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.splash.Splash"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also, create a theme in styles.xml for the splash forwarding activity.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Here I just used the accent color for a background that matches the following splash activity for easier transition. It would avoid the grey in your case. There are other alternatives like Tushars solution, but this works for my use case

Hope this helps